# Prove metacyclic group is generated by two elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a metacyclic group. If we have a short exact sequence $1\to C_m\to G\to C_n\to 1 $ with $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$, then we have an epimorphism $\pi:G\to C_n$ but how can we conclude that $G=\langle a,b \rangle$ where $a$ is a generator of $\ker\pi$, a normal cyclic subgroup of order $m$ of $G$. Also, what about $b$, where will it come from? We know that $G/\ker\pi \cong C_n$, but why does kernel has to be cyclic and isomorphic to $C_m$.

Also, if $H\le G$, then why does there exist $c,d\in H$ with $H\cap\ \langle a \rangle=\langle c \rangle$ and $H=\langle c,d \rangle$.

Comment: You are told that $\ker \pi \cong C_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Exactness at $G$ implies that the kernel of $\pi$ is equal to the image of the map $\psi : C_m\to G$. Exactness at $C_m$ implies that the kernel of $\psi$ is $1$, so $\psi$ is injective, and hence, $\ker\pi$ is isomorphic to $C_m$. Therefore, $\ker\pi=\langle a\rangle$, with $a\in G$ of order $m$.  Since $\langle a\rangle$ is normal in $G$, we have $C_n\simeq G/\langle a\rangle$. In other words, the quotient group $G/\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic of order $n$. Choose a generator $b\langle a\rangle\in G/\langle a\rangle$.  Every element of the quotient $G/\langle a\rangle$ is some power $b^k\langle a\rangle$ of the generator $b\langle a\rangle$, with $0\leq k<n$.  And so $G$ is the (disjoint) union of the cosets $b^k\langle a\rangle$ of $\langle a\rangle$.  But, for each such $k$, the coset $b^k\langle a\rangle$ is the set $\{ b^ka^i\mid 0\leq i < m\}$. In other words, every element of $G$ has the form $b^ka^i$, for some $i$ and $k$, which means that $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$.